# swing and jogl usage in a windowed application

Tags: java, jogl

I have a problem solving a problem concerning jogl and swing. i want to use jogl whit swing components but it doesn't refresh all the time. how can i repaint, refresh the opengl "image" in the swing component (update).when i change the position of my opengl primitives and i call a repaint() or an invalidate function then the screen turns black.
If somebody managed to over come this obstacle please reply to this topic
i used the demo application from the netBeans plugin (GLJPanel or Canvas)
thanks , zsala

Comment: hmmmm revalidate() + repaint(); ???

Comment: fixed problem.Anyone having the same problem should implement JOGL canvas and put that  canvas in the place of the canvas in use by the JFrame.Implement GLActionListener and you're done. Refreshing continuosly with no problem.

Comment: Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Problem fixed. Anyone having the same problem should implement JOGL canvas and put that canvas in the place of the canvas in use by the JFrame.

Implement GLActionListener and you're done. It's refreshing continuously with no problem.